# How to perform asynchronous tasks in fixed interval of time

Tags: ruby, asynchronous

The goal is to perform an async task(file read, network operation) without blocking the code. And we have multiple such async tasks that need to be executed at a fixed interval of times. Here is a pseudo code to demonstrate the same.

```
# the async tasks should be performed in parallel 
# provide me with a return value after the task is complete, or they can have a callback or any other mechanism of communication
async_task_1 = perform_async(1)

# now I need to wait fix amount of time before the async task 2
sleep(5)

# this also similar to the tasks one in nature
async_task_2 = perform_async(2)

# finally do something with the result
```

I'm reading that in ruby I've 2 options forking, threading. The is also something called as [Fiber](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Fiber.html). I also read that due to GIL in the basic Ruby, I won't be able to make much use of threading. I still want to stick to the base Ruby.

I've written some parallel code previously in OMP and Cuda. But I've never got a chance to do that in Ruby.

Can you suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use threading in (MRI) Ruby provided no two threads are executing at precisely the same time. If one thread is waiting for IO (network, disk, etc.) then the others are free to do whatever it wants. If one thread is sleeping, the others are not impeded. In JRuby you do not have this limitation and can use as many threads as your processor supports. In MRI Ruby this means you can use *up to* 100% CPU, but no more. On JRuby you can use 1600% if you have 16 cores, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to you the `concurrent-ruby` gem with its [async feature](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Async.html). This will work great, as long as your tasks are IO bound. (As you said they are)

There you have a async feature to perform your tasks. To wait the amount of time between your 2 async calls you can use literally the [sleep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html) function

```
class AsyncCalls
  include Concurrent::Asnyc

  def perform_task(params)
    # IO bound task
  end
end

AsyncCalls.new.async.perform_task("param")
sleep 5
AsyncCalls.new.async.perform_task("other param")
```

Comment: Thanks, for now, this really looks like something one can use. Currently I've used Ruby Threads to implement the same. I'll share my answer too.